# The name for data reported by an interested party like a manager, parent, or doctor?

Tags: dataset, terminology, reporting

Can anyone help me find the right name for something?

I get that we have "self-reported data", where a member of your sample is reporting their own values of a variable, but is there a name for data reported by a person related to the subject?

For example, what is the term for data reported by a parent about their child's education, or by a manager about their colleague's work quality? Data where the problems of self-reporting are still present but it's not actually reported by the subject?

Comment: I am not aware of a dedicated name. Why do you think that you need one? I can see that such data might raise problems of bias and selection, but that might be best discussed w.r.t. particular variables. Would the name you want apply only to seniors (in age or status) reporting on juniors? What about student evaluations of teachers or courses, complaints about the police, etc.?

Comment: Hi, @NickCox. I was just writing out a description and I wanted to write something like "we will use a mixture of measurements and self-reported values to evaluate the subject" but 'self-reported' felt odd. Given that we are subject to the judgement of others -- doctors, managers, teachers, therapists, researchers, friends  -- it occurred there might be a term for this kind of judgement.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. As said, I don't know a term and I suspect that you would need to explain it any way. "Self-reported data" is ... self-explanatory. But  for what you describe,  "self-reported" is in my view not just odd, but also wrong! It's like nonsense in various places about self-plagiarism. Using one's own material repeatedly may be a bad idea, or against some rules, but it's not plagiarism.

Comment: Yeah, I've rewritten the sentence "The flawed observations of weak-willed humans" will have to do.

Comment: "Third-party evaluations / reports / estimates"? (Caveat: I'm neither a native speaker nor a statisician)